# How can I prevent the same task executed one OVER another?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have a task that pulled data from API and then do system automation (deleting, renaming, ...) with respect to a database (SQLite). I set the task to be executed every 5 minutes. However, sometimes the task takes more than 5 minutes to complete, hence two task run in parallel. This is not good because SQLite database is locked to the task in 0 minute.

How can I have, either,

- the task will not be executed unless the previous task has already finished or
- the second task queued-up and executed directly after the 0 minute task finished?

I have tried to use global boolean to prevent the task to be executed when it is running, like this.

```
automate_is_running = False
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=5))
def automate():
    if not automate_is_running:
        automate_is_running = True

        automate_all()

        automate_is_running = False
```

But that returns `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'automate_is_running' referenced before assignment` error. What should I do?

Comment: Well for a start, you'd have to use `global` within the function. But this still won't work as you want, because each Celery worker is its own process and data is not shared between processes. You'd need to use some kind of external mutex, eg a file on disk or an entry in the db.

Comment: Or you could have only one worker running only one task at a time, or even set a time limit for each task. Refer to the configuration here: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for a start, you'd have to use `global` within the function. But this still won't work as you want, because each Celery worker is its own process and data is not shared between processes.

You'd need to use some kind of external mutex, eg a file on disk or an entry in the db or cache. There's an example [in the Celery cookbook](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time) that uses memcached.

Comment: Have been looking through the example, but I cannot understand it. I only have one function without any parameter necessary, `automate()`. But the example have `self` parameters that I am not sure what is the importance.

Comment: Additionally, I have this error `TypeError: automate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self`.

Comment: It's just an example. If your task is not a method of a class, don't use `self`.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Celery task decorator will always convert it to class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it periodic, schedule it once in the beginning and always schedule next execution at the end of the task. Also make sure that failed task is retried.
The error `TypeError: automate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` is because Celery `task` decorator creates a task object so you need to accept it's instance as the firs argument `self`.
The following code will run the task once as soon as possible and then always 300 seconds after the task is succesfully finished. It will also retry as soon as possible on failure.
To immediately trigger the task again, either replace `self.apply_async(countdown=300)` with `self.delay()` or pass `countdown=0`.

```
@task
def automate(self):
    try:
        automate_all()
    except Exception as exc:
        raise self.retry(exc=exc)
    else:
        self.apply_async(countdown=300)

automate.delay()
```

Try to use specyfic exception class instead of `Exception`. I don't know what your code does and what exceptions you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a scheduler with celery beat and call your second task at the end of your first task.

celery.py (Celery 2.3)

```
from django.conf import settings
from celery.schedules import crontab

settings.CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'runs-every-5-minutes' : {
        'task': 'automate',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/5'),
        'args' : (),
     },
}
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import task

@task(name='automate')
def automate():
    automate_all()
    run_second_task()
```

Documentation:

celery 2.3:
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/v2.3.3/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

celery 4.1
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules